# Функция возврата последнего элемента любого массива

Tags: c#

Но так, чтобы не кидалось исключение. В идеале вернуть null. Как мне переделать этот код?

```
public static T Last<T>(T[] array)
        {
            if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
                throw new NullReferenceException();

            return array[array.Length - 1];
        }
```

Comment: 
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
            return default(T);
        return array[array.Length - 1];
    }

Так как не все типы могут быть null.

Comment: @argamidon, я, конечно, дурной, но не до такой степени. Но искренне надеюсь, что это не вы поставили минус -1. А то как-то неправильно получается - и минус и ответ Ваш неправильный :-)

Comment: @Valeriy Karchov, спасибо, сам уже нагулил. Старая болячка - нет бы сперва быстро найти ответ, а потом уже спрашивать.

Comment: Нет. я не минусовал. на тебе плюсик.

Comment: @argamidon, да не обязательно. Будет мне уроком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public static T Last<T>(T[] array)
    {
         if(array == null) return default(T);

         // Возвращаем последний элемент.
         return array.Last();
    }
```

Comment: Last() выбросит исключение, если массив пуст. Решение @Valeriy Karchov под ответом более корректное.